# How to code a scalable muti-process program using semaphores in C

Tags: c, process, multiprocessing, scalability, semaphore

I am trying to code a scalable mutli-process program using semaphores. I already done the multi-process part with semaphores but now I am trying to make it scalable. 
The method I would like to implement is adding another semaphore per process that will tell the process how many times he has to run through his code. The problem is that I don't know how to initialize the other semaphores and I am not sure of how to code it altogether.

So my question : how to initialize the other semaphores and what semop should I use ?

I understand that without a code sample it might be hard to answer but I cannot publish the code, if you want more information about my problem feel free to ask.
Thank you for your time and your answers.

Code sample :

```
/*INITIALIZATION*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

union semun {
    int val;
    struct semid_ds *buf;
    unsigned short *array;
} sem0, sem1, sem2;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int key=ftok("/tmp",'L');
    int id=semget(key,3,0600 | IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL);

    sem0.val=1;
    sem1.val=0;
    sem2.val=0;

    semctl(id,0,SETVAL,sem0);
    semctl(id,1,SETVAL,sem1);
    semctl(id,2,SETVAL,sem2);
    return 0;
}



/*FIRST PROCESS*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

void first(int d){
    struct timespec* ts;
    ts=malloc(sizeof(struct timespec));
    ts->tv_sec=0;
    ts->tv_nsec=1000*d;
    int i;
    char name[6]={'S','T','A','C','K',' '};
    for(i=0;i<6;i++){
        putchar(name[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
        nanosleep(ts,NULL);
    }
}

struct sembuf in = {0,-1,0};
struct sembuf out = {1,1,0};

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    int key=ftok("/tmp",'L');
    int id=semget(key,0,0);
    while(1){
        semop(id,&in,1);
        first(strtol(argv[1],NULL,0));
        semop(id,&out,1);
    }
    return 0;
}

/*SECOND PROCESS*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

void first(int d){
    struct timespec* ts;
    ts=malloc(sizeof(struct timespec));
    ts->tv_sec=0;
    ts->tv_nsec=1000*d;
    int i;
    char name[4]={'O','V','E','R'};
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        putchar(name[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
        nanosleep(ts,NULL);
    }
}

struct sembuf in = {1,-1,0};
struct sembuf out = {2,1,0};

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    int key=ftok("/tmp",'L');
    int id=semget(key,0,0);
    while(1){
        semop(id,&in,1);
        first(strtol(argv[1],NULL,0));
        semop(id,&out,1);
    }
    return 0;
}


/*THIRD PROCESS*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>

void first(int d){
    struct timespec* ts;
    ts=malloc(sizeof(struct timespec));
    ts->tv_sec=0;
    ts->tv_nsec=1000*d;
    int i;
    char name[5]={'F','L','O','W','S'};
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        putchar(name[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
        nanosleep(ts,NULL);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

struct sembuf in = {2,-1,0};
struct sembuf out = {0,1,0};

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    int key=ftok("/tmp",'L');
    int id=semget(key,0,0);
    while(1){
        semop(id,&in,1);
        first(strtol(argv[1],NULL,0));
        semop(id,&out,1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here we have three process and i am using semaphores. Now what if i want to write the first word(process 1) x times, the second y times and the third z times. What i want to do is adding another semaphore to each process, the value of these semaphores will be the number of times the process must run through it's code. Can someone help me with that, i don't know how to semop on the count semaphores.

Comment: Semaphores need some shared memory. I am not sure they are scalable. I guess that to have really scalable computation you need to use the message passing paradigm (but that is not sufficient).

Comment: I don't see why the method i am trying to implement wouldn't be scalable, one of the semaphore is a countdown for the process(each time a process runs through his critical code this semaphore is decremented) and the other one is a common semaphore used to order the processes.

Comment: Because technologically (and geometrically) you cannot have many thousands of processes (or cores) accessing the same semaphore without pain (you cannot have thousands of wires reaching the same RAM cell). BTW, you should *edit your question* to publish a small sample code (not your real code) to illustrate your question.

Comment: Even so, doesn't change the scalability. I am going to publish a sample of simplified situation

Comment: the use of semaphores is mainly to coordinate the access to a specific/critical resource, like a file or a specific datum.  If you want to track how many times a process has 'looped' through its' code, use a global static variable in the process and increment that variable on each pass through the process loop.

Comment: No i don't want to track the number of execution, i want to block access to process 2 if process 1 hasn't loop x times already. This means that process 1 decrements the value of sem 1' each times he goes through his code and process 2 keeps checking if sem1'=0. I can't use a global variable for that or i loose atomicity.

Comment: Nobody can help me ? I am getting a bit desperate.